# nlohmann JSON: serialize an array like int*?

Tags: c++, arrays, json

I need to serialize an array of int into a json object.

```
int* myObject = new int[5] { ... }
```

I cannot find any solution to this. Even using a vector.
Also, I cannot put my json "manually", since this array isnt fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by "serialize into JSON object"? What is JSON object in your environment? JSON data are usually represented as Unicode strings (or UTF8 text files).

Comment: A question like this needs to include what you have actually tried and what errors/problems you ran in to. It's really no harder then looping over your array and adding the numbers one by one.

Comment: Why didn't a vector work? And why aren't you using a vector to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would use the [`basic_json::array()`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a9ad7ec0bc1082ed09d10900fbb20a21f.html#a9ad7ec0bc1082ed09d10900fbb20a21f) helper method that constructs a json array, and the [`basic_json::push_back(val)`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_ab4384af330b79de0e5f279576803a2c7.html#ab4384af330b79de0e5f279576803a2c7) member function for appending values to an array. In this example, `the_size` refers to the number of elements in `myObject`.

```
auto arr = nlohmann::json::array();

for (int i = 0; i < the_size; ++i){
    arr.push_back(myObject[i]);
}
```

In the future, I would recommend that you browse [the documentation](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json.html) of a tool like this, to see if you can find anything helpful. Most things you would want to know about a software library should be answerable in the documentation.